# Exclude Alphabet and Special character from Alphanumeric string in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can we exclude all alphabet from string keeping only numeric value in seperate column using spark 2.0 with scala.

Input

```
  "ActivalteTime": "PT5M", 
  "ReActivalteTime": "xy20$",
```

Output

```
  "NewActivalteTime": "5", 
  "NewReActivalteTime": "20",
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly generalized approach to handle an arbitrary list of columns to be extracted for numeric content using [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "A", "PT5M", "xy20$", "M100.1!"),
  (2, "B", "QU6N", "uv%", "N200.2&")
).toDF("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5")

val colsToExtract = Seq("C3", "C4", "C5")
val colsRemained = df.columns diff colsToExtract

val prefix = "New"

df.select(colsRemained.map(col) ++ colsToExtract.map(c =>
    regexp_extract(col(c), "([0-9.]+)", 1).as(s"${prefix}$c")): _*
  ).show
// +---+---+-----+-----+-----+
// | C1| C2|NewC3|NewC4|NewC5|
// +---+---+-----+-----+-----+
// |  1|  A|    5|   20|100.1|
// |  2|  B|    6|     |200.2|
// +---+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Regexp_extract`** function to extract only the digits from the string.

```
val df=Seq((""""ActivalteTime": "PT5M","""),(""""ReActivalteTime": "xy20$",""")).toDF("text")

df.show(false)
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------------------+
|text                       |
+---------------------------+
|"ActivalteTime": "PT5M",   |
|"ReActivalteTime": "xy20$",|
+---------------------------+
```

**Using `Regexp_extract`:**

```
df.withColumn("num",regexp_extract($"text","(\\d+)",1)).show(false)

+---------------------------+---+
|text                       |num|
+---------------------------+---+
|"ActivalteTime": "PT5M",   |5  |
|"ReActivalteTime": "xy20$",|20 |
+---------------------------+---+
```